# Should I also send an email to the second author? Or should I at least wait for some time for the first author to potentially respond?

Tags: publications, email

I am currently studying some research papers, and was unable to replicate one of the calculations (I get a different result than what was stated by the authors). I have carefully studied that part of the paper and checked over my work multiple times, so I think it's reasonably likely that there's an error. The paper in question has two authors, and I have sent a very nicely worded email including my calculations to the first author. Should I also send an email to the second author? Or should I at least wait for some time for the first author to potentially respond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably would have been better to send to both initially. But since that option isn't open, perhaps you can wait a reasonable time for a reply. But, if the mail was "informational" rather than requesting feedback, then you might not get a reply.

But, a week or so is a reasonable wait time. You can also send a follow up, but to both.

Comment: It was indeed (explicitly) requesting feedback.

Comment: Just include both on future correspondence unless they request otherwise.

Comment: Even though they are both full professors, they no longer work at the same institution, and the first author (the one I emailed) is much older and more experienced than the other (in fact, he seems to be at the end of his career, and I'm a bit concerned that he won't respond).

Comment: Don't guess. I'm old and at the end of my career (and past), but I respond.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. I'll wait and see if he responds; if not, then I'll email the other.

Comment: @ThePointer Remember it's summer for most of the population, and people (even professors!) of all ages like to go on vacation in summer. Best to not expect a reply within several weeks perhaps.